# neo4j how to enable fulltext search for docker

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to enable fulltext search in a neo4j docker container and was following this: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fulltext-search-in-neo4j/

I setup the config directory as a volume. Is there a way to dump the conf/neo4j.properties to see what's currently there? Not sure if that's even a thing or if I just need to create the file. I tried creating the file, then attaching to the running docker container and running the neo4j-shell and running `index --get-config node_auto_index` but that just says `No such node index 'node_auto_index'`.

I also just tried putting

```
# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false.
node_auto_indexing=true
Then in the same file add the node property keys to be auto-indexed.

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled.
node_keys_indexable=name,title,tagline
```

in the bottom of the neo4j.conf file after I created a dump of it.

Any suggestions or has anyone done this successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I never figured this out, but ended up using the APOC functions for now.

I'm most likely end up indexing with solr to get better fulltext search filtering (:sigh) .